# If $\{f_n\}$ is a measurable sequence of functions, then $\{x : \lim f_n(x) $ exists $\}$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Was hoping someone could help me out on this problem (self-study not hw).

If $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions on $X$, then $\{x : \lim f_n(x) $ exists $\}$ is a measurable function.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: I believe Folland shows that both the limsup and liminf of such a sequence of functions is measurable. Use this fact.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a sketch. I'll let you fill in the details.

Both $\limsup f_n$ and $\liminf f_n$ exist for all $x \in X$ and are measurable functions. The set in question can also be written as:

$$
E = \left\{x \in X : \lim f_n(x) \text{ exists}\right\} = \left\{ x \in X : \limsup f_n(x) = \liminf f_n(x) \right\}
$$

Define:

$$
h(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{ if } \limsup f_n(x) = \liminf f_n(x) = \pm\infty\\
\limsup f_n(x) - \liminf f_n(x) & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
$h$ is a measurable function (why?). The set $E$ can also be written as $E = h^{-1}(\{0\})$. Thus, it's measurable.

Comment: $h$ is not defined on the set $\limsup f_n = \liminf f_n = \infty$ (and similarly for $-\infty$) so as written it is not necessarily a function.  I'm not sure how limits are defined in whichever text the OP is using, but it may be necessary to restrict to the set where this is a real number as well.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian Thanks for your comment. That's a good point that I shouldn't have omitted. This issue is actually addressed by the textbook before this exercise.

Answer (score 8):

By definition $\liminf f_n(x) = \sup_{n \geq 0}\inf_{m \geq n} f_n(x)$. Any $\sup$ or $\inf$ of a family of measurable functions is again measurable, therefore $g(x)=\liminf f_n(x)$ is measurable. The same is with $h(x) =\limsup  f_n(x)$.

Your set is just $\{x : h=g\}$ and this is measurable as a consequence of the fact that the sets $\{x: g<h\}$ and $\{x : g>h\}$ are both measurable.

Comment: Also, $h-g$ is measurable, and $\{0\}$ is a Borel set, so $(h-g)^{-1}(0)$ is measurable.

Answer (score 8):

Another proof not using $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ (a bit lengthy, though).

We know that, given a fixed $x \in X$, the sequence $f_n(x)$ converges iff it is a Cauchy sequence. We will construct sets using this idea.

Let $E_{n,m,r} = \{ x: |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq \frac{1}{r}\}$. This set is a preimage of $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|$, which is a measurable function due to the fact that absolute value is a continuous function, and difference of measurable functions is measurable.

Now, we can define $T_{n_0, r} = \{ x: |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq \frac{1}{r}, \forall n,m \geq n_0 \}$. This set is a countable intersection of $E_{n,m,r}$, which are measurable.

Then $S_{r} = \{ x: \exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n,m \geq n_0,   |f_n(x) - f_m(x)| \leq \frac{1}{r} \}$. This set is a countable union of $T_{n_0, r}$.

Finally, the desired set is just $\bigcap_\limits{r=1}^{\infty} S_r$, which of course is measurable.