# Inverse of Borel set is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Just a short question.

I was reading [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326639/if-f-n-is-a-measurable-sequence-of-functions-then-x-lim-f-nx-ex) and got a question about one of the comments. In the second answer, @geekazoid said that

> Also, $h−g$ is measurable, and $\{0\}$ is a Borel set, so $(h−g)^{−1}(0)$ is measurable.

The question is that why he mentioned about $\{0\}$ is a Borel set.

(Since I don't have enough reputation, I cannot but to make another question.)

Comment: Measurable means inverse image of any Borel set is measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $B:=\{0\}$ is Borel and $h-g$ is measurable, $(h-g)^{-1}(B)$ is Borel - measurable.

Use the Definitions of "Borel set" and "measurable function" !

Comment: Thank you for your answer!