# $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)$ is measurable, but what if the limit only exists for $x\in E \subset X$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I would like to follow up with the question that was asked previously
[If $\{f_n\}$ is a measurable sequence of functions, then $\{x : \lim f_n(x) $ exists $\}$ is measurable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326639/if-f-n-is-a-measurable-sequence-of-functions-then-x-lim-f-nx-ex/326643#326643)

I am hoping one can help me out with what Halmos's "Measure Theory" on (section 20 "Sequences of Measurable Function") means by:

---

The set 
$$
E = \left\{x \in X : \lim f_n(x) \text{ exists}\right\} = \left\{ x \in X : \limsup f_n(x) = \liminf f_n(x) \right\}
$$
where {$f_n$} are the sequeces of measurable functions whose domain is X, has measurable intersection with every measurable set. Consequently, that the function $f$ defined by
$$f(x)=\lim f_n(x)$$
for every x where limit exist is a measurable function.

---

I understand that E is measurable. But $f(x)$ is given only at the value at $x \in E$ and values at other points in X is not specified.

More explicitly, according to Halmos, the definition of a measurable function includes that f be a function of X. That is,
$$f:X\rightarrow\ \Bbb R $$

Since $E \subseteq X$ where E does not necessary be equal to $X$, giving the values of f(x) at E is not enough to specify a function on X.
In other words,
$f(x)=?$ at $x \in X-E$ where ? denotes unspecified values.

For example, if $f_n$ do not have any limit, then $E$ is an empty set. 
$f$ is completely unspecified in X. Setting the arbitrary values of f(x) for all x in X will not be measurable function in general.

I think I am missing something, it would be great if someone can clarify what Halmos could have meant.

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is your question here and how does it differ from the one you asked previously?

Comment: Hi D.R., sorry for the confusion. The question is almost same as previous. I recasted the problem that was asked 6 years ago, but in more detail about the unclear part that wasn't answered previously. The core of the questions is, how can f(x) defined only at the $x \in E$ be a measurable function, which has its domain $X$? As mentioned above, $E$ does not necessary be equal to $X$. In the extreme case $E$ may be empty set. it seems like f(x) defined only at empty set do not certainly seem to be a even a function of X.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right; it doesn't make any sense to say that $f(x) = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)$ is a function $X\to \mathbb R$. I think the correct interpretation is to think of $f(x)$ as a function $E\to \mathbb R$, which then is measurable according to the arguments in Halmos (that you seem to have no issue with).

Another reason why I think this is the appropriate conclusion to take is because another measure theory textbook (my personal favorite), explicitly specifies the hypothesis that the limit exists for all $x\in X$: [image: MIRA excerpt]

Comment: Thank you! I think that definition makes sense. Could you tell me what textbook has this definition (2.48)?

Comment: @sharkbear page 36.