# Determining if the set of x with limit points being rational is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

We consider a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of measurable functions where $f_n : A \subseteq \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$. By the following [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326639/if-f-n-is-a-measurable-sequence-of-functions-then-x-lim-f-nx-ex), we have that the set $\{x \mid \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \text{ exists}\}$ is measurable.

I want to consider a more restricted set, namely, let $S = \{x \in [0,1] \mid \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) \in \mathbb Q\}$. Is $S$ itself measurable? Intuitively it would seem that since we are restricting our initial set of $x$ where $\lim f_n$ exists to a much smaller set, it should not be measurable, how might prove this, or prove that it is measurable instead?

Comment: for a particular rational, is $\{x: \lim_n f_n(x) = q\}$ measurable? Then, the countable union of measurable is measurable